# window.location.assign(url) vs window.location = url?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I'm wondering what the arguments are for using one vs the other. I am familiar with the other properties like `window.location.pathname`. But as far as I can tell, assigning to `window.location` has identical behavior to calling `window.location.assign` and passing it the url.

Why use one or the other? I prefer `assign` because it's more explicit whereas assigning to `window.location` has implicit, veiled magic in its setter.

Is there an argument for one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same:

> Whenever a new value is assigned to the location object, a document will be loaded using the URL as if location.assign() had been called with the modified URL. Note that security settings, like CORS, may prevent this to effectively happen.
>   (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)